# How do I get the absolute coordinates and sizes of all html elements to a json array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, angularjs

I have this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/UPEEW/122/ which is filled with angular ng-repeat. Now I would like to get the coordinates and sizes of all html elements inside the wrapper.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <span class="logo">Logo</span>
      <span class="title">title</span>
      <span class="info">info</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
       <div class="timeline"></div>
       <div class="activities-months" ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="Main">
            <div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:40">{{n}}</div>
       </div>
       <div class="activities"></div>
       <div class="footer"></div>
       <div class="activities-titles"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I do this with jquery .position() for example? Do I need to loop through every element? BTW: It would be nice, if I got the possibiltiy to write classes or styles inside my json array too.

Comment: Loop over the elements with `.each`, then get their coordinates with `offset().top` and `offset().left`

Comment: Will this work for angular created elements too?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? They're in the dom.

Comment: any way I do this for all children of wrapper? Kind of this? `$('.wrapper')children().each(function() {
    console.log("x: " + $(this).offset().top + ", Value: " + $(this).offset().left);
});`

Comment: got it. forgot the . between children and $('wrapper')

Comment: Yep :) That's what I was writing. did it work?

Comment: not really. I only get the descendand children, not all nested elements. as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/UPEEW/124/

Comment: Oh, if you want all nested elements, you can go `$('.wrapper').find('*').each(...`

Comment: Nice :) I have added this as an answer, please validate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.wrapper').find('*').each(function() {
       console.log("x: " + $(this).offset().top + ", Value: " + (this).offset().left);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. As I already asked, it doesnt seem to give me the angular elements correctly. see this output:
`x: 71, y: 211, width: 20, height: 50` just twice inside the console.log instead of 40 times with different x positions.

Comment: shoot... just added document.ready before.. not it works like a charm http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/UPEEW/128/